# How to pick a SE site when they have overlapping scopes?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I recently posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022029/how-to-change-the-cursor-on-hover-in-openlayers-3) on Open Layers 3, a JS mapping library that has its own tag on both Stack Overflow and [the GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Both site have roughly the same amount of questions tagged with that particular tag [openlayers-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayers-3).

I finally chose to post on SO because I already have an account and am active here.

Was my decision justified? What would be the guideline for choosing a site when they are overlapping? Where would the question have the best chances of being noticed and answered?

EDIT : Also, would it be acceptable to cross-post the same question to both sites?

Comment: A lot of sites have overlap. Is your question for "Professional and enthusiast programmers?" If so, keep it here.

Comment: From MSE: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)  See also the [tag cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-posting)

Comment: See also [Is Stack Overflow's scope supposed to be strictly disjoint from that of other Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270427/is-stack-overflows-scope-supposed-to-be-strictly-disjoint-from-that-of-other-st)