# Why does Stack Overflow partition out programming questions to many different sites?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, closed-questions, site-crossover

I often come across excellent philosophical questions that the experts on Stack Overflow would be well-positioned to answer. However, the SO format guidelines require specific questions related to a specific problem, and general architecture and philosophical questions are to be avoided (note that this does not preclude philosophical answers - to the contrary).

While there are a plethora of questions that are not well-formed, with some tweaking they could be good gathering points for learning about good architecture by example.  Other questions ask for recommendations on using a specific tool, and some of those questions (and answers) have the highest up-vote totals I have seen.

It seems to me that partitioning out questions to multiple sites only ensures that the crop of qualified experts that would best be able to answer such questions is diminished, thus reducing the overall quality and quantity of answers. Therefore, I want to understand the rationale of these limitations in an effort to be a better contributor to the sites.

We already have a good system in place via tags to filter down questions to topics that are relevant to you.  Why the additional partition, which adds an order of magnitude of complexity required to browse relevant questions?

**As an example**, I was recently confounded on how to distribute my UI buttons evenly across the window. Googling ["distribute buttons evenly wpf"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=distribute+button+evenly+wpf) yields, as its first result,  [this answer from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910222/spacing-buttons-equally-across-a-window-in-wpf).  Now, I figure this question is off-topic; however, the answer was exactly what I was looking for and found it on the first try.

Comment: Perhaps such a question is better suited for http://meta.stackexchange.com/, ironically?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Does it pay to spin off sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271989/464709)

Comment: See, there is the rub- too many places to post results in confusion and ambiguity.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm not sure the referenced question is a duplicate, as my question is related specifically to programming-type questions that would best be answered by programmers, but get partitioned to another site for being "off topic" - I understand the rationale to have sites around specific technologies or non-programming concepts.

Comment: That's why I did not vote to close as a duplicate, and only said the question was related to yours, and a possible one. Keep your shirt on :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - thank you and it was certainly informative. I just wanted to clarify the viewpoint that I am coming from.

Comment: @Oded That's irrelevant, since this question is specifically about *programming* questions.

Comment: I will never understand why they have split SO and why broad questions are not welcome. Thanks to this politics queue is flooded with extremely bad code samples and question "why this code fails". Also questions are closed without any consistency. Some totally subjective ones remain open, while others are closed for 100 artificial reasons.

Answer (score 7):

Stack Exchange focuses each site on a specific subject.  By doing so, you attract subject matter experts for that particular subject.  Basically, for all of the same reasons that the Internet does not consist of just one site to rule them all.

Computing is a huge subject area.  Having sites focused specifically on theory, research, code and design insures that subject matter experts are available that have an interest in, and a focus on, those specific topic areas, and gathers questions in each subject area under one roof.  Each site is a brand, of sorts.

For better or worse, stack overflow has evolved into a site about coding questions.  While architectural questions are not categorically off topic on stack overflow, they are usually a better fit on Programmers.  Programmers sometimes gets a bad rap due to its Not Programming Related past, but it has a vibrant community where experts are waiting to answer your conceptual programming questions, including your architectural ones.

If your question is more along the lines of "Why can't I start architectural discussions," those kinds of questions are generally a poor fit anywhere on the network, regardless of the site specialization.

Comment: Agree with the last point- I was referring to more specific questions (e.g. would a message broker be beneficial in my situation).  To your other points, I generally agree - however, in many cases the question directly relates to a technology (as in .Net, C#, etc.) and general answers are not desired. Those questions nonetheless receive negative reception. Personally, as an answerer, I would prefer not to bounce between related topics on different sites.

Comment: You can ask technology-specific questions on programmers.  The questions that they categorically reject are code troubleshooting questions (which rightly belong on stack overflow) and discussion questions.  Your "message broker" question would be perfectly at home on Programmers.

Comment: Can't argue with that. Good point.  Do you know if the number of users between the two sites (active users, answering questions) is comparable? Is that data studied?

Comment: Every numerical metric (users, traffic) is higher on stack overflow.  But the community is not looking specifically for architectural questions to answer there; the smaller Programmers community is much more tightly focused on that subject area.

Comment: So, as an example, lets say a confused user posts a question about how to make a piece of code work. Unfortunately, they make the X vs. Y problem, and really have a structural issue that needs help. In this case, assuming the folks with an eye for architecture are on Programmers, would they be less likely to get the help they need? Not looking for an answer, but it does illustrate a particular difficulty.

Comment: @rmayer06 You can study it. For example: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/250130/recent-activity?days=7 vs http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/250130/recent-activity?days=7 The recent (7 days prior to last dump on Monday) questions:askers:answers:answerers ratios are similar for both sites. Note that's a rough query, just for illustrative purposes, e.g. it does not exclude closed questions or answers to closed questions.

Comment: So, I thought of an interesting parallel to this- think of how a University is organized. They have multiple colleges divided into multiple departments, but each college is basically administered as one unit. Within a department, professors teach classes on both theory and practice. They don't switch departments or colleges to do so (though it does happen occasionally).

Comment: But ordinary mortals like me don't get this. I don't even look at Programmers, because as you mention once it was not-programming related, now I learn it is for architectural questions. It's total mess. And new sites are emerging one after another - it's not clear what and where can be asked. I understand why maths has separate site, but programmers interests are overlapping. It's like it's going to end up with separate site for every tag. Should I expect site dedicated to c++ const-correctness at some time?

Comment: @doc: I've heard this complaint so many times that I don't take it seriously anymore.  The community there has put a lot of effort into cleaning up the site and refining its scope over a period of about a year, so if you haven't visited recently, your argument has no merit.

Comment: I know I won't convince you, but for me this only brings confusion. Stackoverflow and Programmers guidelines are not mutually exclusive and we have even more sites related to programming. Name "stackoverflow" suggests that site would be focused on highly technical, "pro" aspects BTW. It was a bit like that when I joined (at least serious questions were welcome). Now it becomes noob heaven. EOT.

Comment: @doc: The two sites do have some overlap.  That's not in dispute.  The same is true of some other related sites on the network.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems to me that partitioning out questions to multiple sites only ensures that the crop of qualified experts that would best be able to answer such questions is diminished, thus reducing the overall quality and quantity of answers.

There is a false premise here that users must pick just a single site to participate on. It is very common for the "crop of qualified experts" to be members of and participate in multiple sites. For example, being active on SO does not exclude one from also being active on Programmers, Code Review, Computer Science, Game Dev, etc.

In other words, partitioning out questions to multiple sites does *not* ensure that the crop of qualified experts is diminished.

It is essentially equivalent to having subforums in a forum, except in this case the subforums happen to have different domain names instead of different paths on the same domain. Integration between sites is very effective (for example, switching sites, viewing activity on multiple sites, and tracking your activity on multiple sites, is readily accomplished via the status bar and even the main SE site).

It is done this way more for organization than anything else. SO in particular is enormous, it is actually much *easier* for experts to focus on specific areas they are interested in when the questions are kept a bit more organized. I.e. if your interest is primarily in design or theory, you can participate in, say, Programmers, or CS (or *both*) without having to sift through specific questions that you are not interested in. But if your interest is in everything, then you can just as easily participate in SO, UX, etc., as well as everything else. Overall, it's a win.

Comment: Certainly the number of experts for widely-used technologies (e.g. C#) would not be an issue. However, for the more obscure technologies, there is no arguing that partitioning questions to multiple sites reduces the potential audience, especially in gray areas where a question may not be the perfect fit for either site.